# Laravel RedirectIfAuthenticated Route Error

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7

This is mine RedirectifAuthenticated code

When i am Manually going to localhost/admin/dashbaord then its accessible after logging in if i remove this code but when i am writting this code then its not accessible

```
 public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check() && Auth::user()->role->id == 1) {
            return redirect()->route('admin.dashboard');
        }elseif(Auth::guard($guard)->check() && Auth::user()->role->id == 2){
            return redirect()->route('user.dashboard');
        }else
            {
            return $next($request);
        }
    }
}
```

I have this code its gaving Error that `route admin.dashboard not defined **if i Mnaually go to route admin.dashbaord then its Accessible**`

Comment: can you post your admin.dashbaord route code pls

Comment: Are you sure you are referencing a route and not a view file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been done the Problem i was facing is that in my 'as'=>'admin'so when i try to do php artisan r:l

it was showing admindashboard not admin.dashboard thats why i am getting this error so i put 'as'=>'admin.'
and the problem got solved